# Service definition in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, angularjs

given that service ( just fetching a json on the server )

```
SushiServices = angular.module("SushiServices",[])

SushiServices.factory("DataTypeService",["$http",($http)->
    self = {}
    self._data = []
    self._inilialized = false
    return ->
        if  self._inilialized ==false
            $http.get("data/types.json").success (data)->
                self._data = data;
                self._inilialized = true

        return self._data
])
```

let say i use that service in a controller :

```
ProductListController = ($scope,$rootScope,$http,$filter,DataTypeService)->
    ### 
        EN : manage product list display 
        FR : gère l'affichage de la liste de produits 
    ###
    $rootScope.types = DataTypeService()
```

$rootScope.types is used in a repeated , now the issue is obvious :
- When i render my page , the json has not been fetched successfull yet , so nothing shows up in my repeater.

**how can i design my app so , the template updates itself when something returns from the server ?** thanks

the template :

```
 <span ng-repeat='type in types'>
        <a href='javascript:void 0;' ng-click="addToSelectedTypes(type.id)" class='label trans' style="font-size: 15px" ng-class="getSelectedClass(type.selected)" >{{type.name | capitalize }}</a>
      </span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you return `self._data` from the function returned from the service. Return whole `self` object (from the function returning from `DataTypeService` factory) and adjust the view to use the `types._data`. Then the markup should update automatically.

Or, you can make some preloader which will be displayed while no data available yet:

```
<div class="preloader" ng-show="!types._initialized"></div>
```

And your repeater will be hidden for a while (and displayed when data loaded correctly):

```
<div ng-show="types._initialized">
    <span ng-repeat="type in types._data">
        <a href="javascript:void 0;">{{type.name | capitalize }}</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @camus The reason returning `self._data` the way you do is a problem is because you are just returning the empty array instance. Once the fetch completes it *replaces* the `self._data` instance with a new array instance, but this replacement will never be seen by the rest of the application; the rest of the application will still be referring to the old, empty array instance. Doing it the way zbynour suggest ensures that the application is always looking at the most recent value in the `types._data` aka `self._data` field, i.e. what's *really* in there right now.

Comment: hey you know what , you are both super smart , so the angular can watch a who object like that ? anyway , that's clever , and angular is awesome.

Comment: Yes @Supr described it perfectly. The problem is you have to allow angular to be able to watch that.